# Clarification On A Pigeonhole Principle Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, chessboard

I have encountered the following pigeonhole principle problem. I'm not sure what the question means, so I would like to clarify what it means:

> 17 rooks are placed on an 8×8 chessboard. Prove that there are at least 3 rooks that do not threaten each other.

What does it mean that 3 rooks do not threaten each other? Does it mean that there is a set of 3 rooks such that no pair involving any of the 3 rooks, involve two rooks that threaten each other? Or does it mean that there are 3 pairs of rooks, the pairs consisting of any 2 rooks, such that in the pair, the rooks do not threaten each other? Or does it mean something else entirely?

Could I get an explanation of what the question means (**please avoid any hints/solutions**)? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: It means your first interpretation; there will exist three rooks, call them A, B, and C, such that A does not threaten B, B does not threaten C, and C does not threaten A.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Got it, thanks!

Comment: Threatening is mutual ofc.